# Flask - Do I need to use secure_filename() on uploads to S3/Google Cloud?

Tags: flask, werkzeug

In the Flask documentation for [file uploads](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/), they recommend use of `secure_filename()` to sanitize a file's name before storing it.

Here's their example:

```
uploaded_file = request.files['file']
if uploaded_file:
    filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename) # <<<< note the use of secure_filename() here
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return redirect(url_for('display_file',
                            filename=filename))
```

The documentation says:

> Now the problem is that there is that principle called **“never trust user
>   input”**. This is also true for the filename of an uploaded file. All
>   submitted form data can be forged, and filenames can be dangerous. For
>   the moment just remember: **always use that function to secure a
>   filename before storing it directly on the filesystem.**

With offsite storage (S3 or Google Cloud), I will not be using Flask to store the file on the web server. Instead, I'll rename the upload file (with my own UUID), and then upload it elsewhere.

Example:

```
blob = bucket.blob('prompts/{filename}'.format(filename=uuid.uui4()))
blob.upload_from_string(uploaded_file.read(), content_type=uploaded_file.content_type)
```

Under this scenario, am I right that you do you ***not*** need to invoke `secure_filename()` first?

It would seem that because I (a) read the contents of the file into a string and then (b) use my own filename, that my use case is not vulnerable to directory traversal or rogue command-type attacks (e.g. `"../../../../home/username/.bashrc"`) but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct.

You only need to use the `secure_filename` function if you are using the value of `request.files['file'].filename` to build a filepath destined for your filesystem - for example as an argument to `os.path.join`.

As you're using a UUID for the filename, the user input value is disregarded anyway.

Even without S3, it would also be safe NOT to use `secure_filename` if you used a UUID as the filename segment of the filepath on your local filesystem.  For example:

```
uploaded_file = request.files['file']
if uploaded_file:
    file_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_uuid))
    # Rest of code
```

In either scenario you'd then store the UUID somewhere in the database.  Whether you store the originally provided `request.files['file'].filename` value alongside that is your choice.

This might make sense if you want the user to see the original name of the file when **they** uploaded it.  In that case it's definitey wise to run the value through `secure_filename` anyway, so there's never a situation where the frontend displays a listing to a user which includes a file called `../../../../ohdear.txt`

---

[the `secure_filename` docstring](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/src/werkzeug/utils.py#L391-L408) also points out some other functionality:

> Pass it a filename and it will return a secure version of it.  This
>       filename can then safely be stored on a regular file system and passed
>       to :func:`os.path.join`.  The filename returned is an ASCII only string
>       for maximum portability.
>       On windows systems the function also makes sure that the file is not
>       named after one of the special device files.

```
>>> secure_filename("My cool movie.mov")
'My_cool_movie.mov'
>>> secure_filename("../../../etc/passwd")
'etc_passwd'
>>> secure_filename(u'i contain cool \xfcml\xe4uts.txt')
'i_contain_cool_umlauts.txt'
```